# calculate distance between 2 locations using Mapquest while the location written in Hebrew

Tags: javascript, location, distance, mapquest

I'm trying to calculate distance between 2 locations in Hebrew using Mapquest.
I followed the documentation of Direction API in https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/directions-api/route-matrix/post/.

This is what i'm tring to run:

```
  let request = require('request')

  let postData = {
    "locations": [
      "החשמונאים, תל אביב",
      "דרך השלום, תל אביב"
    ],
    "options": {
      "allToAll": false,
      "unit": "k",
      "locale": "he_IL",
    }
  }

  let url = 'http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=mykey'
  let options = {
    method: 'post',
    body: postData,
    json: true,
    url: url
  }
  request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('error posting json: ', err)
      throw err
    }
    let headers = res.headers
    let statusCode = res.statusCode

    console.log('body: ', body)
  })
```

Thats the response:

```
body:  {
  allToAll: false,
  distance: [ 0, 0 ],
  locations: [
    {
      dragPoint: false,
      displayLatLng: [Object],
      adminArea4: '',
      adminArea5: '',
      postalCode: '',
      adminArea1: 'IL',
      adminArea3: '',
      type: 's',
      sideOfStreet: 'N',
      geocodeQualityCode: 'A1XAX',
      adminArea4Type: 'County',
      linkId: 282934907,
      street: '',
      adminArea5Type: 'City',
      geocodeQuality: 'COUNTRY',
      adminArea1Type: 'Country',
      adminArea3Type: 'State',
      latLng: [Object]
    },
    {
      dragPoint: false,
      displayLatLng: [Object],
      adminArea4: '',
      adminArea5: '',
      postalCode: '',
      adminArea1: 'IL',
      adminArea3: '',
      type: 's',
      sideOfStreet: 'N',
      geocodeQualityCode: 'A1XAX',
      adminArea4Type: 'County',
      linkId: 282934907,
      street: '',
      adminArea5Type: 'City',
      geocodeQuality: 'COUNTRY',
      adminArea1Type: 'Country',
      adminArea3Type: 'State',
      latLng: [Object]
    }
  ],
  time: [ 0, 0 ],
  manyToOne: false,
  info: {
    statuscode: 0,
    copyright: {
      imageAltText: '© 2020 MapQuest, Inc.',
      imageUrl: 'http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif',
      text: '© 2020 MapQuest, Inc.'
    },
    messages: []
  }
}
```

It's cannot recognize the addresses but I see thats possible because when I enter the same addresses inside the "Lat/Lng Finder" tool (https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/tools/latitude-longitude-finder/) it's giving me the right place. it's even give me the right distance when I using the lat and lng instead of the name of the location.

What do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 5-box format for the addresses. It would look something like this: locations:[{street: "3601 Walnut St",city: "Denver",state: "CO",postalCode: "80205",country: "US"}, {street: "1555 Blake St",city: "Denver",state: "CO",postalCode: "80202",country: "US"}]

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work. thats what I tried: 
"locations": [{ 
"street": "החשמונאים","city": "תל אביב","country": "IL" }, { "street": "דרך השלום", "city": "תל אביב", "country": "IL" }]

Comment: If you try open.mapquestapi.com does it work better?